# Change part of URL

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, ember-router

I'm using slugs instead of ids in app. Slug has following structure: `bla-model-name-bla-bla-id` where `bla-model-name-bla-bla` is slugifyed name of model and `-id` is model ID.

App do not care about "name" part it is here for SEO and UX... App take only "ID" part and using it to retrieve model from API.

Sometimes slug changes and I want app to redirect (after model retrieved) to a URL with correct "name" part.

I tried to do something like this:

```
App.PostRoute = Em.Route.extend
     ...
     ...
     afterModel:(post,transition)->
        ...
        # checkinkg slugs
        if current_slug != valid_slug
           @transitionTo 'post', post
```

But in this case we lost all everething after PostRoute. If desired URL was `/post-old-invalid-name-33/comments` then after "slug fixing" I have `/post-valid-name-33`. So we lost `/comments` part

Of course this is a simplified example. Real app has not only `/comments` resource but much more.

How to change part of URL or how to redirect without losing rest of transition?

Comment: Were you able to get this working? I am facing the same problem... although I'm still stuck on how to get the `:post_id` param inside of `afterModel` in order to check if the slugs differ.

Comment: @dignoe that's easy: ```transition.params``` (```transition``` is the second parameter passed to ```afterModel()```)

Comment: would love to see this answered.. please add how you solved it if you did :)